# Import Excel to SharePoint List Tutorial Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, excel, html

I am attempting to import/copy excel data into a SharePoint list.
I am following this tutorial to a tee: https://www.udayagirisreekanthreddy.com/2017/12/reading-excel-file-using-html-5-and.html?showComment=1595334657969#c673835051392810211

however, when I add the CEWP to the page, I get this error in the HTML Source area of my site page:

```
 <div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read cac6ffe5-5784-4c44-a528-00bbecdca71c" 
 id="div_cac6ffe5-5784-4c44-a528-00bbecdca71c" unselectable="on">
    </div>
    <div id="vid_cac6ffe5-5784-4c44-a528-00bbecdca71c" unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Any help or other references are greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you pointing the CEWP towards a HTML file?

Comment: Hi Michael, yes I am

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of HTML code in that tutorial, any part of it could be causing an error forcing SharePoint to hide the webpart. You can debug the code to find the exact issue. In Chrome, press F12, then Ctrl + P, search for your HTML file. Place a break point at the top somewhere and step through the code using F10.

Otherwise, you can start stripping the code away to see if you can eliminate the error. If you can't find the file loading in Dev tools, then there's an issue with the path to the HTML.

There are also 4 external script files being loaded in the sample code, make sure they are actually being loaded by checking the Dev Tools Console tab for errors.